# Deserialize Json array of array in c#

Tags: c#, json

I am new to c# don't know how to get a JSON array of array stored in a 2d array. I am having a JSON file with students marks like

```
[
    [10,5,4],
    [9,6,3]
]
```

and out of this I am using this code but getting error out at `JArray`

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
```

I have tried some other approaches as well but nothing helped basically what I want to do is want to create a boolean 2D array which will be populated on the basis of the above JSON record and for that purpose I want to populate the array with JSON content.

Comment: why you need to use JArray?

Comment: i was just searching for a solution and found this on many websites

Comment: ok but given you are using c#  it will be better to use a POCO and your json is not valid

Answer (score 0):

With the following valid JSON

```
{ "data" : [
    [10,5,4],
    [9,6,3]
]
}
```

The following class was used to hold the parsed data

```
public class RootObject {
    public IList<IList<int>> data { get; set; }
}
```

which can be parsed using Json.Net

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RoootObject>(json);
```

and the content accessed

```
var x1 = root.data[0][1]; // 5
var x2 = root.data[1][1]; // 6
```